# dropping columns in panda if they are NaN before a certain date

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a large dataframe that has measurements in it with different start dates. I now want to cut this down to a dataframe that only contains measurements that are older than a certain date.

I want to turn this:

```
            A    B     C     D     E
1950-11-01  3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1950-12-01  2   NaN   NaN   NaN    5
1951-01-01 NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    4
1951-02-01  3    4    NaN   NaN   NaN
1951-03-01  2    3     4    NaN    5
```

into this:

```
            A    E
1950-11-01  3   NaN
1950-12-01  2    5
1951-01-01 NaN   4
1951-02-01  3   NaN
1951-03-01  2    5
```

That is, I want to ***only*** drop columns that are completely filled with NaN before 1951. If there are single NaNs (from measurement failures) in the data, it should remain.

I can find the columns in question with `df['1940':'1950']`, to select only the time in question and then do `df.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')`, but this way, I am loosing the parts after 1951, which is interesting to me. I could use the output of this, to extract the labels of the columns in question, and then pick those from the original dataset, but it is a 6 level multiindex and the whole df has 2000 columns, so that's certainly not the optimal way to do it.

Essentially, I want to do something like

```
longtermdata = alldata.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all that are NaN before 1951')
```

How do I best do that?

Comment: `df[(df['date'] > any value) & (df['date'] < any value)].dropna(axis=1, inplace= True)`

Comment: Seems like my dates are not keyed as dates, since this results in a keyerror. Maybe have to play around with this too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
begin_date = pd.to_datetime('1951-01-01')
```

## find the columns to keep

```
cols = ~df.loc[:begin_date].isnull().all()
```

Initially I had

```
cols = df.columns[~df.loc[:begin_date].isnull().all()]
```

but the `df.columns` is indeed not necessary for `.loc`. Thanks to @unutbu

## result

`df.loc[begin_date:, cols]` gives

```
            A       E
1951-01-01  NaN     4.0
1951-02-01  3.0     NaN
1951-03-01  2.0     5.0
```

`df.loc[:,cols]` gives

```
            A       E
1950-11-01  3.0     NaN
1950-12-01  2.0     5.0
1951-01-01  NaN     4.0
1951-02-01  3.0     NaN
1951-03-01  2.0     5.0
```

## begin_date

the `df.loc[:begin_date]` includes the `begin_date` If that is not what is expected, replace it with `df[df.index < begin_date]`

Comment: What does the ~ before the df do? Seems promising, but I'm loosing all rows before 1951 when I run it.

Comment: @unutbu `df[cols]` needs the columns names, but this can be solved by changing that to `df.loc[:, cols]`

Comment: @jc-cl the `~` is an inversion or `not`

Comment: OK, so my cutoff of stuff before 1951 was a typo on my side, but now `df[cols]` fails with `ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer`. EDIT: Gotta check that with the comment/edit above. I just CTRL-C'd my ipython session…

Comment: losing everything before 1951 is because of the `df.loc[begin_date:, cols]` if you remove the `begin_date` there, it should give everything